# Replace tags for html content

Tags: c#, entity-framework

That's how if I have some content that I want to replace from a tag to html content how do I add html content to the site I've written it takes her.

fx:

```
<p> hello world </p>
<p> hello world </p>
<p> hello world </p>
<p>{{alert}}</p>
```

Where I've written alert there, then it will get a video that is in my block's table.

`{{alert}}` ---> `<div class="alert alert-success">
  <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
</div>`

```
var listBlocks = _dbContext.Blocks.ToList();//Get {{banner}} here
var text = _dbContext.ContentInfo.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1).ContentText;//text content

for (int i = 0; i < listBlocks.Count; i++)
{
    if (listBlocks[i].Tag.Equals(text))
    {
        text += text.Replace(listBlocks[i].Tag, listBlocks[i].Value);
    }
    //How can I do this?
}
```

It must be alike. where I have written her, it just replaces the point I have written

No matter where tag is, it should replace it as it is in the block table.

Comment: I wouldn't store formatted text in the database in the first place. Use placeholders in the UI markup and bind them to (replace them by) flat text coming from the database.

Comment: Do you have a look at how it could be done? @GertArnold

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate English isn't your first language.

From what I understand, I think you just need to change

```
if (listBlocks[i].Tag.Equals(text))
{
    text += text.Replace(listBlocks[i].Tag, listBlocks[i].Value);
}
```

to

```
text = text.Replace(listBlocks[i].Tag, listBlocks[i].Value);
```

or if you like

```
if (listBlocks[i].Tag.Contains(text))
{
    text += text.Replace(listBlocks[i].Tag, listBlocks[i].Value);
}
```

This is because you don't need to append the replacement to the end of `text`, and also it's unlikely that `text==listBlocks[i].Tag` because text just contains the tag.

Comment: Yes, sorry for my English. What I just think is that it's basically just gotta grab the area that I've got in and it's going to let all other common html code be in peace.